# Replace spaces and newlines with a comma in php

Tags: php

I searched but couldn't find anything that helped

So, I have a bunch of data I need to basically just put commas between, the data all comes from records so it comes in like:

```
13
566
888
958
898
```

and I need to output it like:

```
13,566,888,958,898
```

even better if I can move any 2 digits one over like:

```
566,13,888,958,989
```

I know it should be pretty simple, so basically I just made a form, pass it with GET and then read the variable from the url, then I'm trying to use str_replace(" ",",",$outtext) to get replace the spaces with commas so I can echo it out and just copypasta it in real quick, problem is, I think the data comes in with a new line and I don't know how to replace that, I've tried "\n" and "%0D%0A" but it doesn't replace it, it just gives it right back to me with the spaces.

Anyway, here's the code I'm using, maybe someone can tell me the simple thing that I'm missing,

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['intext'])) {
    $outtext=$_GET['intext'];

    $newout=str_replace(" ", ",", $outtext);

    echo $newout;
    //testing
    //echo(str_replace(" ",",","$outtext"));
}
?>
```

and the html

```
<form name="indata" id="indata" method="get" action="index.php">
        <textarea id="intext" name="intext"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

I also thought about tossing it into an array and imploding it, but it's been a while and I forget how to do that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The newline could still be registering if you've got the "\r\n" version of a newline - you're removing "\n" and leaving "\r" behind.

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/',',',str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n"),' ',trim($str)));
```

Cleaner (more legible) version:

```
$str = preg_replace('#\s+#',',',trim($str));
```

Comment: Yes, awesome, thats what it was, this works perfectly.  Another question, how can I remove the final "," as in, it comes out 13,566,569, and I just want 13,566,569 (I'd also like to move that 13, in between those numbers, but that may be more complex for this quick and dirty necessity)  EDIT: nvm I'm a derp, I'll just echo in substr($output, 0,-1)

Comment: @salty You may want to `trim` the string before applying the replacements - see edited answer

Comment: Thanks SmokeyPHP, trim is definitely more elegant :)

Comment: @salty On the topic, just an FYI - trim has a second parameter. Though not required in this instance, you could put after my line `trim($str,',');` thus removing any commas from either side of `$str`
http://uk3.php.net/trim

Comment: I noticed it does it like this Text1 <br,> Text2 <br,> Text3... Is there any other way to do it so i can then split the above and use it as an array or will the above work just the same?

Answer (score 4):

As you said, using an array then imploding is a good approach:

```
$input = trim($_GET['intext']);
$numbers = preg_split('/\s+/', $input);
echo implode(',', $numbers);
```

This trims the input of any padding, splits into an array based on whitespace, then implodes the array with commas.

Answer (score 3):

First remove any extra white spaces or carriage returns and new lines from your input then replace it with comma.

```
 <?php
  if( isset($_GET['intext']) ){
      var_dump($_GET['intext']);

      //get and trim the input
      $value = trim($_GET['intext']);

      //clean the input by removing extra white spaces
      $value = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $value );

      //replace spaces with comma
      $value = str_replace(" ", ',', $value);

      //echo output
      echo $value;
  }
 ?>

 <form name="indata" id="indata" method="get" action="">
    <textarea id="intext" name="intext"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In *nix (and I believe mac as well) systems you have lines separated by LF "\n" and on windows you have CR+LF "\r\n". You could do a `str_replace` or a `preg_replace` and replace the spaces, the CR+LF and then the LF. You could use a regex to replace anything that resolve in your regex with a comma.

Show the code that is not replacing line feeds and the source of the string and perhaps I can tell you why it isn't working.