# Replace textarea line break to save text to Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I need to replace the newlines in a textarea with the string ", " for storing it in a database. For example, the following string, taken from the textarea:

```
hi!
line break!
```

Would be replaced with:

```
hi!, line break!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace spaces and newlines with a comma in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838096/replace-spaces-and-newlines-with-a-comma-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.value.replace(/\n/g, '')`. This will replace all occurrences of new line in the text area with empty string.

```js
var textWithoutLineBreak = document.getElementById('txtArea').value.replace(/\n/g,'');
console.log(textWithoutLineBreak);
```

```html
<textarea id="txtArea">hi!
line break!
</textarea>
```